# android How to add button over other button?

Tags: android, overlay

I'm trying to add button on other button exactly on same position with same width,and height.

I thought i can do that like these codes,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1;
LinearLayout root;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);

}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams size = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(b1.getWidth(),b1.getHeight());
    int[] locations = new int[2];
    b1.getLocationInWindow(locations);

    Button a = new Button(this);
    a.setLayoutParams(size);
    a.setText("new Button");
    a.setX(locations[0]);
    a.setY(locations[1]);
    root.addView(a);
}
```

}

and XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="semo.msoft.myapplication.MainActivity">
<Button
android:id="@+id/b1"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

but, result was like this,

[resultImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4TGi.png)

I thought it should be correct but it seems be wrong, new button had little bit smaller width and height. Additionally , the position of new button was totally wrong.. I don't know why,, someone who know about this, please help

Comment: Change your root to `<FrameLayout>`.

Comment: @Shaishav Thanks, but i tired too, but it seems like this [framLayout result image](https://i.imgsafe.org/3793a73b2c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is working perfectly fine on my machine. I basically just changed the way you are setting `LayoutParams`:

```
    int[] locations = new int[2];
    b1.getLocationInWindow(locations);

    Button a = new Button(this);
    a.setLayoutParams(b1.getLayoutParams());
    a.setX(locations[0]);
    a.setY(locations[1]);
    a.setText("new Button");
    frameLayout.addView(a);
```

PS: You need to change the `root` to `<FrameLayout>`. `LinearLayout` just isn't made to handle overlapping views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I used that code in  public void on WindowFocusChanged(boolean has Focus){} so this was problem! Thank you